# How to write a sql query and django queryset

Tags: mysql, sql, django

Here i am having two tables Book,Publications

Book tables is having the following fields

```
id, book_name, pub_id
```

And Publications table is having the following tables

```
id, pub_name
```

Using the pub_name how can i get the book_name in SQL query and Django query

Comment: SQL: By joining the tables: `SELECT * FROM publications p JOIN books b ON b.pub_id = p.id WHERE p.pub_name = ???` – note that you might get multiple rows that way if there exist more than one books for the same publication.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships. Please post your model instead of just column name. may the following can help you, 
Book.objects.filter(<the_fk_col_in_model>__pub_name == 'some name').

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do in Django ORM is,

```
book = Book.objects.filter(pub__pub_name='publisher_name')
```

This will give you a queryset, to get the book name do this

```
book_name = book.first().book_name if book.exists() else ""
```